# %matplotlib notebook does not respect figure.facecolor

Tags: matplotlib, jupyter-notebook

I am using Jupiter notebook with jupyter themes (one dork). However, I still want my figure to have a white face color and not adapt to the theme.

This can be accomplished using...

```
%matplotlib inline
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor='w')
ax.plot(np.arange(40), np.arange(40))
```

[image]

HOWEVER, when using %matplotlib notebook, this does not work ...

```
%matplotlib notebook
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig, ax = plt.subplots(facecolor='w')
ax.plot(np.arange(40), np.arange(40))
```

[image]

Any thought on this behavior??

Comment: apologize, second iteration should be %matplotlib notebook instead of %matplotlib inline. Thanks for the edit!